# How to dynamically create a xml file and set it to the upload control using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically create a xml file using `jquery` or `javascript` and i don't want to download it. I want to assign it to the upload control. Then on button click i want to send it to the controller. How can i able to do that using jquery. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is controller you mantioned. Do you means server?

Comment: Yah server. I want to download it in the server

Comment: You can assign $.ajax({
    dataType: 'xml',
}) to your button

Comment: how can i dynamically create an xml file. And i want to send the created file. That's what you are saying right?

Comment: actually I didnt realy get the question. Do you want to save this dinamicly created xml file to the yousers computer and than upload to the server?

Comment: I want to send huge data to the server. But it is not passing to the controller. So i want to append the data to the xml file and upload the file using upload control and then i will parse the xml data and take the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send a xml file generated by JS in the client side because what you will have is not a file is just a string. But you can send the string to the server using the jquery post function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). So create your valid XML string:

```
var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?>" +
"<root>" + getXML() + "</root>"
```

And send it to the server:

```
$.post('test.html',{ data : xml }, function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Yes this is the way if your question is that :)